# mysqli_fetch_assoc returning "Array" values rather than actual data from Mysql DB

Tags: php

I am trying to retrieve records from my mysql db which includes blob, varchar and int types.

When i return this as a list and iterate through it, it returns a concatenated string with "Array" e.g "ArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArray"

i tried to wrap the result into json with json_encode and instead it just gives me an empty string

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
require './connection.php';


$obj = json_decode($_GET["x"], false);

$imageQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . $obj->page . " WHERE Type = '" . $obj->tab . "'");
$imageQuery->execute();

$resultSet = $imageQuery->get_result();

$jsonData = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($resultSet) > 0) {
while ($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultSet)) {
    $jsonData[] = $array;
}
$json = json_encode($jsonData);
echo $json;
}
?>
```

Comment: Converting blobs (binary large objects) into json doesn't sound like a good idea. Json doesn't really support binary data.

Answer (score 0):

I have problem with this logic of getting results. First you use database as an abstraction($db->prepare, $imageQuery->execute()) then you try to get number of rows as a function with connection handler of object : mysqli_num_rows($resultSet).

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
require './connection.php'; // create autoload.php better

//in data
$obj = json_decode($_GET["x"], false);

//sql prepare
$dhs = $db->prepare("
 SELECT * 
 FROM " . $obj->page . " 
 WHERE Type = '" . $obj->tab . "'");
$dhs->execute();
$sqlResult = $dhs->get_result();

// fetch all rows
$jsonResult = array();
while ($row = $sqlResult->fetch_assoc()) {
  $jsonResult[] = $row;
}

//return json array
echo json_encode($jsonResult);
```

Comment: _"First you use database as an abstraction"_ - What do you mean by that? Your answer is very unclear.

Comment: also, it actually didnt work. it produced the same result.

Comment: mysql_query function directly handles sql to say mySQL. Object oriented approach like PDO makes layer in front of the db and can be used as object(abstraction layer, something->fetch()). That gives you option to change DB without changing all code everywhere.   If this dont work, the problem is elsewhere. Did you tried the sql itself in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: The error in your code is this: $imageQuery is an mysqli_stmt object. $resultSet is an mysqli_result object. But then you are trying to use them procedural as mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultSet) wich expects a reference to the connection, not an object. the correct one is going for objects again so: $resultSet->fetch_assoc()